# Unable to call static library function from Java class

Tags: java, c++

Say I have a static C++ lib, DataPacker.lib and is linked to a shared dynamic link library called Command.dll.

The static library exposes following function,

```
//Datapacker.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java__Observer_sendToClient
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//Datapacker.cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java__Observer_sendToClient
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject)
{
//Print
}
```

Now I tried to call above function from java class as follows,

```
//Observer.Java
class Observer
{
static{
System.loadLibrary("Command");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
sendToClient();
} 
catch (Throwable t){
System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" +  t.getMessage());
}
}
private static native void sendToClient();
}
```

But am getting following exception from java,

> "Native code library failed to load.Observer.sendToClient()V"

The call works fine when it is moved from DataPacker.lib to command.lib. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c++ linker didnt add DataPacker.lib code into Command.dll.
if you want to call function you must write proxy function in the Command.dll for DataPacker.lib(global export function for java calls)
for example dll code:
        #include 
        #ifdef _*cplusplus
        extern "C" {
        #endif
        JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java*_Observer_sendToClient
        (JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject);
        #ifdef __cplusplus
        }
        #endif

```
    //DatapackerDLL.cpp
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java__Observer_sendToClient
    (JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject)
    {
     DataPacker::sendToClient();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks kain. SO you mean there is no way to call function defined in static lib Datapacker.lib without modifying command.lib right?Also I wanna know any difference between windows and solaris C++ compliers. The function can be invoked successfully in solarais platform.

Comment: The issue is solved by modifying the .def file. I have added  exposed function name in command.def file and it is able to call through command.dll. Thanks for your help.